# Livewire encountered corrupt data when trying to hydrate the [component-name] component

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

"Livewire encountered corrupt data when trying to hydrate the [create-post] component. Ensure that the [name, id, data] of the Livewire component wasn't tampered with between requests."

Ive got this error above... when using wire:model like when i type something on textarea or add something in file input...

HTML

```
    <div class="create-post-wrapper">
        <form class="create-post" enctype="multipart/form-data" wire:submit.prevent="storePost()">

            <div class="upload-icon">
                <input wire:model="postFile" type="file" id="files" name="file" onchange="cfile(event)" multiple style="display:none;">
            </div>
            <textarea wire:model="postText" name="post-text" cols="40" rows="10" placeholder="What's on your mind?"></textarea>
        
            <button class="submit-btn">
                <i class="fas fa-pen-nib"></i>
            </button>

        </form>
    </div>

livewire component

namespace App\Http\Livewire;
use Livewire\WithFileUploads;

use Livewire\Component;

class CreatePost extends Component
{

    use WithFileUploads;

    public $postText;
    public $postFile = [];


    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.create-post');
    }
    public function storePost(){

    }
}
```

never an anwswer .. i just freshly downloaded a laravel project and install livewire, still got the error

Comment: Are there any javascript code?

Comment: found the problem ... i mistakenly added the basic HTML template into my view when its already inside my layout file, i took it off and that sort of fixed it.